Resolve service that expects an HttpClient and a string
I have the following class:
class MyClass(HttpClient client, string whatever) { }

Now I want to create an instance of this class using the .NET DI-container in my console-app:
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyClass>();

But how would I pass the string-argument to the MyClass-instance?

AddTransient<MyClass>() is this supposed to be AddTransient<MyService>()?

generally you should avoid injecting primitive types. There are a number of options - where and when do you know the value of string whatever?

Do you want to pass string whatever dynamically or you will have a single/limited number of such strings per app lifetime?

actually the string is static during the apps lifetime, it comes from the args and contains the users token used per request to that instance

Personally I would just create a special type to hold the string:
class MyService(HttpClient client, MyServiceSettings settings)
{
    // use MyServiceSettings.Whatever
}

class MyServiceSettings
{
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}

With the following registration (add Microsoft.Extensions.Http to get the access to AddHttpClient):
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new MyServiceSettings { ... } ); // register correct value
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<MyService>(httpClient => ...); // will register MyService as transient

Alternatively you can look into factory approach:
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("someName", httpClient => ...);
serviceCollection.AddTransient(sp =>
    new MyService(
        sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("someName"), 
        "{getYourString}"));


actually the string is static during the apps lifetime, it comes from the args and contains the users token used per request to that instance

In some cases you can just setup the HttpClient itself, for example if token is passed as header then you can do something like:
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<MyService>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("tokenHeaderName", "tokenValFromArgs");
});


I assume I can even omit the AddHttpClient-line, as I don't want to provide any default configuration for it and just use whatever the IHttpClientFactory returns me.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain As far as I remember parameterless AddHttpClient still needed for factory to be registered in the DI.

I tested it and got a default-client by CreateClient, so seems to work.

MyServiceSettings looks a bit like an Options Pattern. And IOptions are already there.

@Ralf yes, MyServiceSettings can be consumed via the options pattern..
